How can I include events from a subscribed calendar in my work calendar?
The organization I belong to uses Google Workspace, and we rely on Google Calendar sharing to find times to schedule meetings.
At home, I have a large and active family, and we use the Cozi calendar for family organization (Cozi shared family calendar) which supports sharing (webcal) to my Google Workspace account.
This allows me to see both my work events and my family events in Google Calendar.
However, Google does not include the Cozi-subscribed events in my work calendar, so when my colleagues look at my calendar (e.g., to schedule a meeting with me), they do not see any home events.
Does anyone know how to get my subscribed Cozi events included in my work calendar?
